# How to return number of selected rows in datagrid to textbox in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I would like to select multiple rows (not necessarily in any particular order) and return number of selected rows to the textbox.

Something like:
You have selected 'x' rows.

I was trying to use this kind of method:

```cs
private void SelectedRows(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var selectedRows = SomeDataGrid.SelectedRows.Count.ToString();
    RowCount.Text = "You have selected " + selectedRows + "rows";
}
```

but to no avail.
There was an error saying that DataGrid do not contain SelectedRow definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DataGrid` does not have a `SelectedRows` property (if you're using Visual Studio, IntelliSense should have warned you about this). Instead, use the property `SelectedItems`.